# Unexpected regex result with a single space

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Can somebody please tell me why a space comes up with 2 matches for the below pattern?

```
((?<key>(?:((?!\d)\w+(?:\.(?!\d)\w+)*)\.)?((?!\d)\w+)):(?<value>([^ "]+)|("[^"]*?")+))*
```

Trying to match the following cases:

```
var body = "Key:Hello";
var body = "Key:\"Hello\"";
var body = "Key1:Hello Key2:\"Goodbye\"";
```

This may provide more context:

```
pattern = @"((?<key>" + StringExtensions.REGEX_IDENTIFIER_MIDSTRING + "):(?<value>([^ \"]+)|(\"[^\"]*?\")+))*";
```

My goal is to pull the keys, values out of a command-line like string in the form of [key]:[value] with optional repeats.  Values can either be a with no spaces or in quotes with spaces.

Probably right there in front of me but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: There are no anchors in the pattern and you get partial matches. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't understand what is your expected result?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Added the suggested tags, and provided the intended goal.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because “.”, because a period in regex, marches every character except line breaks

Comment: Obvious answer I would totally agree.. but I do not have a dot other than dot literals

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach:

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> GetCommandLineKeyValues(this string commandLine)
    {
        var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var pattern = @"(?<command>(" + StringExtensions.REGEX_IDENTIFIER + " )?)(?<args>.*)";
        var args = commandLine.RegexGet(pattern, "args");
        Match match;

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
             string key;
             string value;

             pattern = @" ?(?<key>" + StringExtensions.REGEX_IDENTIFIER_MIDSTRING + ")*?:(?<value>([^ \"]+)|(\"[^\"]*?\")+)";

            do
            {
                match = args.RegexGetMatch(pattern);

                if (match == null)
                {
                    break;
                }

                key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
                value = match.Groups["value"].Value;

                keyValues.Add(key, value);

                args = match.Replace(args, string.Empty);
            }
            while (args.RegexIsMatch(pattern));
        }

        return keyValues;
    }
```

I took what I call the "pac-man" approach to Regex.. match, eat (hence the Match.Replace), and continue matching.

For convenience:

```
public const string REGEX_IDENTIFIER = @"^(?:((?!\d)\w+(?:\.(?!\d)\w+)*)\.)?((?!\d)\w+)$";
```